# Get all registered BroadcastReceivers for received sms

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have 2 applications that are registered for BroadcastReceiver. I know both of them work, because both of them showing toasts when receiving SMS.
Even so, when i use:

queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0)

I get a list which contains only 1 receiver when i'm checking it inside the BroadcastReceiver. 
My goal is to find out all apps which listen to SMS_RECEIVED

EDIT: 
when i use it outside i do get 2 BroadcastRecievers. Why there is a different?

Answer (score 1):

use the following code instead:

```
List<ResolveInfo> receivers = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"), 0);
```

Comment: That's what i used. My question is why i get different answer when make this query inside the the broadcastReciever (gives me the wrong answer) and outsode (which seems to give me the right answer).